# Script for Creating Copies of Word documents in SQL Server R2 Integration services

Tags: sql-server-2008, service, scripting, integration

I need to write a script in SQL 2008 R2 integration Services  to CREATE copies of Word documents from a database while also creating new primary key (ID) and attributes (such as the paths) .Is this possible? Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are your documents actually stored in the database? Often times only the path is stored in the database and the actual file data is stored on the filesystem.

You will need to create:
1) Filesystem task to copy the word document to the desired location on the filesystem
2) Execute SQL Task to update or insert a record into the database with the new file location

You should use variables for the file names so that way you can easily update your database with the same values.

Comment: Thanks heap for your answer. I will try this out.